# Возврат результата из потока

Tags: c++

Попытался вернуть результат выполнения функции в потоке с помощью лямбда функций. Но почему-то выводится "мусор". Я уже и отладчиком прошелся, и видео на эту тему посмотрел. Все равно не могу понять, почему в result не записывается результат функции

```
int tr(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int result;

    thread th([&result]() {result = tr(3, 10); });

    cout << result << endl;


    th.join(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `th.join();`  должно быть ДО вывода результата

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поменяйте местами строки - вот так:

```
th.join();
cout << result << endl;
```

У вас поток отработать не успевает, как вы уже выводите переменную...

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Вот, типичный пример анонимного минуса и при 159k :)

Comment: для кого то это способ самоутверждаться...

Comment: хороший способ получит голоса «за», пишешь под ответом что тебе поставили голос «против» и не равнодушие люди поставят голос «за»

Comment: @Danis Да-да, вот такой я человек-говно...